# Implement Web3 and IPFS on server side (backend)

Tags: web3js, ipfs

How do I implement Web3 and IPFS on the server side (backend)? I am able to implement on client-side (using web3.js and ipfs.js in HTML script tags) for localhost. However, it fails when I run the same for my https server. Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you add more details to this question, what type of errors you are getting?

Comment: I am using testrpc here to simulate the blockchain.
    
Types of errors:<br/>
1. Pop-up on page load says 'There was an error fetching your accounts.'  
2. In console, 'The page at 'https://dummyaddress.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.'  
3. In console, 'OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:8545/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'. Clarification - I am using truffle v2 for this. The rpc port in truffle.js is set at localhost.  <br/>
4. IPFS XHR Error

Comment: Sorry. I'm unable to fix the formatting at this moment!

Answer (score 0):

Ask this in the Web3 Slack. With IPFS - I think you have to claim an address. With Web3 prehaps it's the HTML tags that's causing it. What are you using as the editor? You could also turn to HTML5 Coin team for answers.

Great question hoping I can ask this for you .